# MX Master mouse too sensitive in Ubuntu

Tags: default-settings, logitech-mouse, ubuntu-17.04

I have a Logitech MX Master mouse (bluetooth) and Ubuntu 17.04.

The mouse is fine with Windows but I find it too jumpy in Ubuntu, and can be trick clicking on into the right place in text and links.

I tried changing the pointer speed in the mouse & trackpad control panel but it makes no difference.

I tried 'xinput list-props' for the input device and got a list but none seemed to be of any use.

Is there any way I can fine tune the mouse?

```
Device 'MX Master':
    Device Enabled (153):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (155): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Accel Speed (570): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (571): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (572):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (573):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (574):   1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (575):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (576):   0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (274): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (275):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (276):    0, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (577): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (578): 0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (579):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (580):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (581):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (582): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (583): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (584):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (585):    0
    Device Node (277):  "/dev/input/event17"
    Device Product ID (278):    1133, 45079
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (586):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (587):   1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can adjust cursor sensitivity by altering value of `libinput Accel Speed` property, as it accepts values between `-1` to `1` (incl. decimal places).

Find the ID of your mouse (which I believe you already did as you ran `xinput list-props`) using `xinput --list --short`, you'll see output similar to following;

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech MX Master                        id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wide Vision HD                         id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Yubico Yubikey 4 OTP+U2F+CCID             id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard                 id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard                 id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech MX Master                        id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

In my case, ID for MX Master mouse is `12`. Once you have the ID, run following.

```
xinput --set-prop 12 "libinput Accel Speed" -0.6
```

Replace `12` with ID of your Mouse that you found earlier, and change `-0.6` to any value that suites to your liking.

Remember that these changes are not preserved across restarts and logins, you'll need to create shell script like following;

```
#!/bin/bash
xinput --set-prop 12 "libinput Accel Speed" -0.6
```

And save it to your Home folder as `fixmouse.sh`, and then open terminal in home folder and run `chmod +x fixmouse.sh`.

Now run `gnome-session-properties` in terminal to open Startup Applications GUI, and add the script you just created to the list.